# Make Windows application work on Mac OS X

Tags: .net, macos, virtualization, virtualbox

Please suggest ways to deliver Windows application (.NET) to Mac OS X. Mono isn't an option, I'm looking for a solution that requires no code changes. I'm considering VirtualBox virtualization (http://www.virtualbox.org). Any other suitable options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives to VirtualBox include Parallels Desktop, VMWare Fusion, and CrossOver Mac.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you know, can I create a system on Windows, using VirtualBox, and use it on MAC, or I need to create it on MAC directly in order to make it work there?

Comment: As far as I know, all of these virtualization solutions would require installing the virtualization software on the Mac.  VirtualBox, Parallels Desktop, and VMWare Fusion also require installing Windows within the virtual environment.  Not sure about how CrossOver Mac works.

By the way, it's spelled Mac, not MAC.  It's not an acronym.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any code changes then having it run under some sort of emulation - be that a virtual machine, or some other way - is the only thing you can do.